# I need to find the factorial of a number using the function "reduce"

Tags: python, python-3.x, reduce

Given a number ‘n’, output its factorial using reduce().

Note: Make sure you handle the edge case of zero. As you know, 0! = 1

```
from functools import reduce

n = int(input())
f = reduce(lambda n : n * (n - 1) if n > 1 else n)
print(f)
```

Also, I need help with this type error mentioned below

```
TypeError: reduce expected at least 2 arguments, got 1
```

Comment: RTL(ovely)M: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Comment: You are getting confused between recursive functions and `reduce`. How, I'm not sure. You can use `f = reduce(lambda x, y : x * y, range(1, n+1)) if n > 0 else 1`.

Comment: The canonical dupe contains _many_ ways to calc the factorial .. including those using `reduce` - I see no reason to create a "specific" question here. Research SO before asking please - this will help you faster.

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` expects two arguments. First a function expecting two args, and second an iterable. The proper code should be like this.

```
from functools import reduce
n = int(input())
f = 1 if n == 0 else reduce(lambda a, b : a*b, range(1, n+1))

print(f)
```

Comment: What about when `n` is zero?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do I correct this code mentioned below:

from functools import reduce

n = int(input())

def fact (n):
    
    if (n == 0):
        
        return 1
    
    else:
        
        return n * fact(n-1)

f = reduce(lambda n: n * n - 1)

print(f)